Kafka Mirror Maker 2 - Does not synchronize all group offsets
I'm running mirror maker, but not all group offsets are syncing, strangely, it starts syncing but doesn't finish.
Command used to synchronize topics, groups and offsets from a source kafka to a destination kafka:
./connect-mirror-maker.sh ../config/connect-mirror-maker.properties
Contents of the connect-mirror-maker.properties file:
clusters = source, target

source.bootstrap.servers = xxxx:9094
target.bootstrap.servers = xxxx:9094
security.protocol=SSL

source->target.enabled = true

source->target.topics = .*

blacklist = [follower\.replication\.throttled\.replicas, leader\.replication\.throttled\.replicas, message\.timestamp\.difference\.max\.ms, message\.timestamp\.type, unclean\.leader\.election\.enable, min\.insync\.replicas]

refresh.topics.enabled=true

refresh.topics.interval.seconds=10

replication.factor=3

checkpoints.topic.replication.factor=3
heartbeats.topic.replication.factor=3
offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor=3

offset.storage.replication.factor=3
status.storage.replication.factor=3
config.storage.replication.factor=3

emit.heartbeats.interval.seconds = 5

replication.policy.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.IdentityReplicationPolicy
replication.factor=3
refresh.groups.enabled=true
refresh.groups.interval.seconds=60
sync.group.offsets.enabled=true
sync.group.offsets.interval.seconds=60
emit.checkpoints.enabled=true
emit.checkpoints.interval.seconds=60

When I consult the source consumer group, the following information is returned:
GROUP               TOPIC                  PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
perf-consumer-67750 poc-kafka-performance4 9          0               776             776             -               -               -
perf-consumer-67750 poc-kafka-performance4 0          0               1165            1165            -               -               -
perf-consumer-67750 poc-kafka-performance4 7          1358            1358            0               -               -               -
perf-consumer-67750 poc-kafka-performance4 1          0               884             884             -               -               -
perf-consumer-67750 poc-kafka-performance4 6          0               679             679             -               -               -
perf-consumer-67750 poc-kafka-performance4 2          870             870             0               -               -               -
perf-consumer-67750 poc-kafka-performance4 5          873             873             0               -               -               -
perf-consumer-67750 poc-kafka-performance4 3          0               1358            1358            -               -               -
perf-consumer-67750 poc-kafka-performance4 4          1317            1455            138             -               -               -
perf-consumer-67750 poc-kafka-performance4 8          582             582             0               -               -               -

But when I do the same query the target Kafka returns:
GROUP               TOPIC                  PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
perf-consumer-67750 poc-kafka-performance4 2          870             870             0               -               -               -
perf-consumer-67750 poc-kafka-performance4 5          873             873             0               -               -               -
perf-consumer-67750 poc-kafka-performance4 7          1358            1358            0               -               -               -
perf-consumer-67750 poc-kafka-performance4 8          582             582             0               -               -               -

As you can see, in this example it replicates the offsets of the partitions that have zero delay and no errors appear in the logs.
In this other case below, it did not complete and maintains the lags:
Source:
GROUP               TOPIC                 PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
perf-consumer-67704 poc-kafka-performance 8          776             776             0               -               -               -
perf-consumer-67704 poc-kafka-performance 9          971             971             0               -               -               -
perf-consumer-67704 poc-kafka-performance 4          885             885             0               -               -               -
perf-consumer-67704 poc-kafka-performance 7          679             679             0               -               -               -
perf-consumer-67704 poc-kafka-performance 1          1068            1068            0               -               -               -
perf-consumer-67704 poc-kafka-performance 3          1351            1351            0               -               -               -
perf-consumer-67704 poc-kafka-performance 2          1165            1165            0               -               -               -
perf-consumer-67704 poc-kafka-performance 5          1067            1067            0               -               -               -
perf-consumer-67704 poc-kafka-performance 0          679             679             0               -               -               -
perf-consumer-67704 poc-kafka-performance 6          1359            1359            0               -               -               -

Target:
GROUP               TOPIC                 PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
perf-consumer-67704 poc-kafka-performance 8          708             776             68              -               -               -
perf-consumer-67704 poc-kafka-performance 9          910             971             61              -               -               -
perf-consumer-67704 poc-kafka-performance 4          809             885             76              -               -               -
perf-consumer-67704 poc-kafka-performance 7          607             679             72              -               -               -
perf-consumer-67704 poc-kafka-performance 1          1011            1068            57              -               -               -
perf-consumer-67704 poc-kafka-performance 3          1314            1351            37              -               -               -
perf-consumer-67704 poc-kafka-performance 2          1112            1165            53              -               -               -
perf-consumer-67704 poc-kafka-performance 5          1011            1067            56              -               -               -
perf-consumer-67704 poc-kafka-performance 0          607             679             72              -               -               -
perf-consumer-67704 poc-kafka-performance 6          1314            1359            45              -               -               -

Even waiting more than 30 minutes without touching these topics, the result is the same.
Does anyone know why this is happening?
Thanks!
I carried out this simulation using both the source and destination clusters with versions 3.5.1 and 3.6.0.
I tested by removing the "blacklist" setting and specifying just one test topic and the same problem occurred.
I also tested the mirror maker with 3 different versions and the problem is the same.
The strange thing is that it starts synchronizing the partition offsets normally, but I didn't complete it.
I also tried using the command:
connect-distributed.sh ../config/connect-distributed.properties
And creating the connectors separately, but with the same problem.
